# How can I close the workbook when Application.run is completed in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub openWorkBook()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\data\" & Cells(2, 1).Value
Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
End Sub
```

My code is shown as above. I open another workbook and use Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks" to refresh all of the formula in the Excel workbook. It takes about 3 minutes to finish formula calculation (Actually it draws data from Bloomberg). And I want the workbook to close after finishing refreshing all data. How to improve the VBA codes above?

Comment: vba is neither java nor python

Answer (score 0):

You could add an optional argument to `RefreshAllWorkbooks` say `blnCloseOnComplete` default `false` then at the end of the function `if blnCloseOnComplete then thisworkbook.close {true/false}` then call like `application.run RefreshAllWorkbooks(true)`

Comment: I have in the answer.  Read about optional arguments.